# Django: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1035: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, django, encoding, nginx, utf-8

Django 1.6
Python 3
Nginx, uWsgi

There are a view topics about this error, but the solutions are not applicable for me.

I have a web application where it is possible to upload a xml file inside a tar-archive for import purposes.

While developing on my local machine running the application with "python manage.py runserver" the import process runs flawless. When running the application on the vServer with Nginx and uWsgi, i get this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError at /sync/upload/
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1035: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The error happens on this last line written by me and the code run behind from there:

```
xml = f.read() <- My line
return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
```

Since the whole thing wokrs on my system but not on the vps, i assume the problem is some kind of configuration issue. So far i've tried to set LANG and LC_ALL before nginx starts as well as providing the encoding='utf-8' attribute when "open(xmlfile) as f". Plus many different approaches trying to encode by hand.

So know i'm out of options.

I'm working from Switzerland using an en_US.UTF-8 ArchLinux machine. The VPS is a Debian machine from which i don't know how to configure the default charset, if this is even related. Any help is welcome.

Thanks and regards,
Adrian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `ascii_decode` explicitly. So language settings are out of scope. `ascii_decode` can decode bytes in the range 0..127. But 0xc3 = 195 > 127. So you are testing your server with another file, that contains bytes with values > 127. Normally, xml-readers take bytes and not strings, so decoding is unnecessary, because the encoding is given inside the xml-file.